# How to formulate this concept as an equation

Tags: math, random, equation

I have this (pseudocode):

```
var a = Math.random(); // returns random number from 0 to 1
```

[image]

I would like to have greater probability of selecting lower numbers just like picture describes. How should equation (code) look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest here is to proceed with Rejection sampling.

Basically you simulate a bi-dimensional variable (x,y) = (Math.random(), Math.random()). It is a point in the square [0,1][0,1]. If the variable (x,y) is in the triangle you drawn, then take x.

x will have the distribution you are looking for.

Pseudocode:

```
x = Math.random();
y = Math.random();

if x+y < 1:
   return x;
```

You could actually get away with it by drawing only one random variable (by computing and inverting the Cumulative Distribution Function), but that's much more complicated in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought about this problem and I came up with something even simpler - var a = 1-Math.sqrt(Math.random()); this is not linear relation but I think it will do its job in my case :) . Thanks for help, I learned something from your answer.

Comment: Indeed, inverting the cdf was easier than I first thought :) That's probably the best thing to do here...

Answer (score 1):

The inverted Cumulative Distribution Function gives

```
1 - Math.sqrt(1 - Math.random()),
```

so

```
 1 - Math.sqrt(Math.random())
```

will give you the distribution you want.

Note that the probability density at 0 must be 2 so that the area under the curve gives a total probability of one.